# Python returns 'UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop..'

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

I am study deep learning with images..
I got this error when I run this code:

```py
from PIL import Image

using_image_num = 10000
batch_num = 2 

for category in classes:
    for j in range(using_image_num):
        img = category[j,:j+784].reshape(1,28,28,1)
        batch = 0
        flow = datagen.flow(img, batch_size = 1, save_to_dir = saved_location, save_prefix = 'augmented_' + classes[i], save_format='png')
        for augmenting_batch in flow:
            batch += 1
            if batch > batch_num:
                break

    print("augmented " + category + " is saved.")
```

---

The error looks like:

```
UFuncTypeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-e9dd2f490a52> in <module>
     15         img = category[j,:j+784].reshape(1,28,28,1)
     16         batch = 0
---> 17         flow = datagen.flow(img, batch_size = 1, save_to_dir = saved_location, save_prefix = 'augmented_' + classes[i], save_format='png')
     18         for augmenting_batch in flow:
     19             batch += 1

UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U10'), dtype('<U10')) -> dtype('<U10')
```

---

When I run this code in colab, it returns results well.

I don't have any idea why this is not working on Jupyter notebook. I operated this code on AWS ec2 server.
At first time, I thought colab and jupyter works similarly, but the results were not.
I find that U10 means unicode .... but I am stuck in this problem without any solution..

Comment: Can you cast classes[i] to string using str(classes[i]) and try running again. It looks like this has to be of string data type.

Comment: I solve this problem with smaller dataset. In my case, the 'classes' was too big to run appropriately. I divided it into smaller parts, and it results well. Thank you for your help.